# Build and run kivy APK: No module named 'kivy._clock'

Tags: ubuntu, kivy, apk

Trying to build and run Kivy APK from Ubuntu 22.04. It builds and the app starts on the device, but immediately terminates with msg: No module named 'kivy._clock'.

Recompilation of Kivy is recommended.

This is what I do and get. Any idea?

```
#------------------------------------------------
# remove existing kivy  
#------------------------------------------------
> source ~/kivy_venv/bin/activate

> pip uninstall kivy

#------------------------------------------------
# build kivy from source
#------------------------------------------------

> cd ~

> mkdir kivy-deps-build 

> cd kivy-deps-build/

> curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kivy/kivy/master/tools/build_linux_dependencies.sh -o build_kivy_deps.sh

> chmod +x build_kivy_deps.sh

> ./build_kivy_deps.sh

> python3 -m pip install "kivy[base]" kivy_examples --no-binary kivy

> export KIVY_DEPS_ROOT=$(pwd)/kivy-dependencies^C



#------------------------------------------------
# build and run APK
# - app starts on the device, 
#   but immediately terminates 
#------------------------------------------------
> source ~/kivy_venv/bin/activate

> cd ~/eclipse-workspace/lvx0_android/buildozerlib

> ./script/rabalder_rcd_bldrun.sh  logcat
# (= buildozer android debug run logcat > log.txt)

#------------------------------------------------
# logcat output
#------------------------------------------------
# ... I python  :    File ".../buildozerlib/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/rabaler_rcd/armeabi-v7a/kivy/clock.py", line 466, in <module>
# ... I python  :  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy._clock'
# ... Python for android ended.


#------------------------------------------------
# virtualenv versions
#------------------------------------------------
#   buildozer          1.5.0
#   Cython             3.0.2
#   Kivy               2.2.1
#       java --version 
#         openjdk 17.0.8.1 2023-08-24
#         OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.8.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04)
#         OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.8.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```